# Clip NetCDF with Shapefile

Tags: gis, geopandas, netcdf, python-xarray, shapefile

I have followed a few solutions found on StackOverflow and the GIS StackExchange, but cannot seem to troubleshoot this error message. I don't have a lot of experience working with GeoPandas, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Attached below is my script:

```
    # Key Module Import(s):
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import xarray as xr
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import cartopy.crs as ccrs
    import geopandas as gp
    import rioxarray
    from shapely.geometry import mapping
    
    # Primary Workspace
    cID = xr.open_dataset('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\countrymask_0.1x0.1.nc',) # NetCDF
    cID[['cell_area', 'CountryID']].transpose('lat', 'lon', 'time')
    cID.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim = "lon", y_dim = "lat", inplace = True)
    cID.rio.write_crs("EPSG:4326", inplace = True)
    
    # Location of Each Shapefile
    BorNA_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\BorNA\BorNA.shp')
    TemNA_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\TemNA\TemNA.shp')
    TroSA_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\TroSA\TroSA.shp')
    TemSA_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\TemSA\TemSA.shp')
    Eur_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\Eur\Eur.shp')
    BorEuras_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\BorEuras\BorEuras.shp')
    TemEuras_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\TemEuras\TemEuras.shp')
    TroAs_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\TroAs\TroAs.shp')
    Aus_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\Aus\Aus.shp')
    NAfr_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\\NAfr\\NAfr.shp')
    SAfr_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\SAfr\SAfr.shp')
    OTH_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\OTH\OTH.shp')
    
    # Clipping Procedure Using RioXarray
    C_BorNA = cID.rio.clip(BorNA_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), BorNA_sp.crs)
    C_TemNA = cID.rio.clip(TemNA_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), TemNA_sp.crs)
    C_TroSA = cID.rio.clip(TroSA_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), TroSA_sp.crs)
    C_TemSA = cID.rio.clip(TemSA_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), TemSA_sp.crs)
    C_Eur = cID.rio.clip(Eur_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), Eur_sp.crs)
    C_BorEuras = cID.rio.clip(BorEuras_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), BorEuras_sp.crs)
    C_TemEuras = cID.rio.clip(TemEuras_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), TemEuras_sp.crs)
    C_TroAs = cID.rio.clip(TroAs_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), TroAs_sp.crs)
    C_Aus = cID.rio.clip(Aus_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), Aus_sp.crs)
    C_NAfr = cID.rio.clip(NAfr_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), NAfr_sp.crs)
    C_SAfr = cID.rio.clip(SAfr_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), SAfr_sp.crs)
    C_OTH = cID.rio.clip(OTH_sp.geometry.apply(mapping), OTH_sp.crs)
    
    # Save Clipped Output(s)
    NC_BorNA = C_BorNA.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\BorNA.nc')
    NC_TemNA = C_TemNA.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\TemNA.nc')
    NC_TroSA = C_TroSA.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\TroSA.nc')
    NC_TemSA = C_TemSA.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\TemSA.nc')
    NC_Eur = C_Eur.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\Eur.nc')
    NC_BorEuras = C_BorEuras.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\BorEuras.nc')
    NC_TemEuras = C_TemEuras.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\TemEuras.nc')
    NC_TroAs = C_TroAs.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\TroAs.nc')
    NC_Aus = C_Aus.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\Aus.nc')
    NC_NAfr = C_NAfr.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\\NAfr.nc')
    NC_SAfr = C_SAfr.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\SAfr.nc')
    NC_OTH = C_OTH.to_netcdf(path = 'E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\Outputs\OTH.nc')
```

**Error received**: ValueError: Assigning CRS to a GeoDataFrame without a geometry column is not supported. Supply geometry using the 'geometry=' keyword argument, or by providing a DataFrame with column name 'geometry' (***@Line 28, i.e. BorNA_sp***)

Thank you all in advance for the assistance, and apologies for what may read a repeat question.

**
FULL TRACEBACK:
**

````
  File "C:\Users\Jordan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "e:\psu\ccar reu\python codex\masking scratch space.py", line 28, in <module>
    BorNA_sp = gp.read_file('E:\PSU\CCAR REU\Python Codex\MASKS\SP_Files\BorNA\BorNA.shp')

  File "C:\Users\Jordan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 253, in _read_file
    return _read_file_fiona(

  File "C:\Users\Jordan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 340, in _read_file_fiona
    df = GeoDataFrame.from_features(

  File "C:\Users\Jordan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 656, in from_features
    return cls(rows, columns=columns, crs=crs)

  File "C:\Users\Jordan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 192, in __init__
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Assigning CRS to a GeoDataFrame without a geometry column is not supported. Supply geometry using the 'geometry=' keyword argument, or by providing a DataFrame with column name 'geometry'```
````

Comment: please post the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors. thanks!

Comment: Updated! Sorry about that part being missing.

Comment: huh. this is weird. what version of geopandas and fiona are you using? can you post the result of `gp.__version__, fiona.__version__`?

Comment: and thanks for the update! technically the traceback starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):`. I think we have all the info here but seeing that makes us feel all warm and fuzzy cus we know we're getting all the details. also - check out the guide to creating a [mre] - ideally you should do the work to figure out exactly what's causing the issue, boil down your code to only the part that's necessary, and see if you can simplify as much as possible before asking, esp if this ends up being a geopandas/fiona issue. See https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for the feedback. As for the result of gp.__version__, fiona.__version__ => Out[5]: ('0.11.1', '1.8.21')

Comment: huh. this one has me a bit stumped. are you sure that shapefile is ok/not corrupted? can you open it with fiona directly? and can you read the other shapefiles?